# Using Cron and CURL in a custom module

Tags: 7, database, cron

I am using a hook_cron (mymodule_cron) in my custom module, but would like to know whether the cron run is successful or not and has sent the data using CURL, and from there, update a specific column value in my sql table. How to get this status?

Part of my codes:

```
$options=array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $urlCron, 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false
);

$CURL=curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($CURL,$options);
$content=curl_exec($CURL);
curl_close($CURL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilise [watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7) at the end of your hook_cron implementation, then implement [db_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_update/7) to update your desired table.